# Transaction and rollback on this code

Tags: php, mysql

Following is my code in which I am making insertion in two different tables. My question is if due to bad server or bad connection or the like. The insertion to the first table being made but not to the second one. Then does the following code will rollback the insertion being done for the the first table and if not then how that can be done?

Note: My table type in Innodb

```
  $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
  $stmt_one = $mysqli->prepare("Insert into TABLE SET $var1 = ?, $var2 = ? ");
  $stmt_two = $mysqli->prepare("Insert into TABLE SET $var1 = ?, $var2 = ? ");
  $stmt_one->bind_param('is',$var1,$var2);
  $stmt_two->bind_param('is',$var1,$var2);
  $stmt_one->execute();
  $stmt_two->execute();
  $mysqli->commit();
  $stmt_one->close();
  $stmt_two->close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

```
try { 
  $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
  $stmt_one = $mysqli->prepare("Insert into TABLE SET $var1 = ?, $var2 = ? ");
  $stmt_two = $mysqli->prepare("Insert into TABLE SET $var1 = ?, $var2 = ? ");
  $stmt_one->bind_param('is',$var1,$var2);
  $stmt_two->bind_param('is',$var1,$var2);
  $stmt_one->execute();
  $stmt_two->execute();
  $mysqli->commit();
  $stmt_one->close();
  $stmt_two->close(); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $mysqli->rollBack();
  echo "Fallo: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

For starting transaction you need turn off auto-committing DB modifications. You do it via `$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);`. It means that all queries-changes DB  must be "fixed"  for  "finish" transaction. Its doing via  `$mysqli->commit();`. While you don't calling `commit` ("fix") - there will be no changes in DB.

In your case ( inserting into 2 tables ): if the insertion to the first table being made but not to the second , will be invoked  exception with `$mysqli->rollBack();`. Since we have not caused сommit transaction (due to exception ), all changes  will be roll back to start point (turning off auto-committing), in other words, we do rollback current transaction.

Comment: okay, one last question will your answered query work in case if insertion being done to the first table and your internet got disconnected means the rollback code `$mysqli->rollBack();` doesn't execute then in that case will the transaction rollback or the insertion to the first table remain there(which in this case is a bug which I am trying to avoid)?

Comment: @user3027531 look: it not depends of your connecting. You run PHP script on server. From this moment no more depends from you. If on second insertion DB return error , rollback саn not be executed only in one case - if PHP script dies ( for example, server falled )